# Positivity condition from integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, polynomials, integral-inequality

Let $f$ be a positive integrable function, and $q$ a polynomial. we assume that for every polynomial $p$ :
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} p(t) f(t) dt <\infty
$$
Knowing only that for all  polynomial $p\neq 0$ 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} p^2(t) q(t) f(t) dt > 0. 
$$
How to prouve that $q$ is a non negative polynomial.
And what can we say if we assume the equality for a subspace of polynomial? (for example for polynomials up to some finite degree)

Edit :
If $f$ is with compact support, using Weierstrass approximation theorem we get that, for all non negative continuous function $h$ :
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} h(t) q(t) f(t) dt > 0. 
$$
So we consider $K$ the compact subset of the support where $q$ is negative then by Uryson Lemma for all $\epsilon$ we can find a non negative function $h$ such that $h(x) =1$ on $K$ and vanishing outside  $K+\epsilon$ and less than one on the third part.
So we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} h(t) q(t) f(t) dt \leq
\int_{K} q(t) f(t) dt + 2M\epsilon 
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) dt 
$$
Which is negative if we assume that $q$  change the sign for $\epsilon$ small enough.

Comment: By "nonzero polynomial" do you mean a polynomial that never vanishes? And by positive polynomial do you mean a a polynomial that is $>0$ everywhere?

Comment: Non zero polynomial means simply $p\neq 0$ and you are right i want that p is non negative  $\geq $ everywhere

Comment: We can get the answer if we assume that $f$ is with compact support by using Weierstrass theorem and Uryson Lemma...